# Load and display js, py, (etc...) files with JavsScript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a static website which will relay only on client-side (no PHP).
I have couple of js and py files, which I would like to display on the site as a code.

I really want to avoid using jQuery and implement everything in JavaScript (lightweight as possible).

```
var codeToDisplay = "<object type='text/html' data='problem001.js'></object>";
document.getElementById('code').innerHTML = codeToDisplay;
```

This doesn't work. What are my options?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AJAX to get the contents of the file and insert it into the element. Use `.textContent` to prevent interpreting it as HTML.

```js
var url = 'problem001.js';
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readystate == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById('code').textContent = xhr.responseText;
    }
}
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.send();
```

```html
<div id="code"></div>
```

Comment: It displays the content of `codeToDisplay` (the string), not the actual file.

Comment: I misunderstood what you wanted.

Comment: The code I want to display is inside the file `problem001.js`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it without AJAX? Maybe with DOM or something. I'm using `pre` and `code` tags to render it as text and not as code.

Comment: I don't think so. `<object>` tries to render it as an object, not just display the raw content.

Comment: And without `<object>`? Is there a JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's `load()`?

Comment: `.load()` uses AJAX.

Comment: So I guess I'll turn to jQuery anyway.. Thanks.